# Why does Apache Nifi throws Connection Load Balance Error?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using nifi in version 1.14.0 and facing a very weird situation.
I have a loadbalanced connection and after disconnection in the cluster (due to out of memory errors)
I'm getting the following error:
Error load balance server -

```
standartLoadBalanceProtocol attempted to receive flowfile from peer for connection with id xxx but no connection exists with that ID
```

Did anyone experience anything familiar? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it sound like this issue? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-9433

Answer (score 0):

I think it relates to this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/NIFI-9695. Please upgrade to NiFi version 1.16 and see if this error happens again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).